# Postfix/LDAP authentication - Restrict select users from connecting to smtp from public IP

Tags: postfix, ldap, authentication, dovecot

In dovecot, I am able to use LDAP to restrict public access to specific users using LDAP user_filter and pass_filter queries. I would like to do the same thing in order to restrict specific users from sending emails from remote IP addresses.

In dovecot, my user_filter/pass_filter is as follows:

```
(&(uid=%u)(!(accountStatus=noaccess))(employeeType=%{if;%3r;eq;10.;LOCAL;REMOTE}))
```

This queries the LDAP database and checks for "noaccess" in the accountStatus field. It also compares the first three digits of the remote IP address with "10.". If employeeType is REMOTE, he can connect from any IP address. If the employeeType is LOCAL, he can only connect from the 10.x network.

Can anyone suggest a way to accomplish the same thing with postfix authentication?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to use Dovecot authentication with Postfix. This gave me a single place to manage authentication for both IMAP and SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

I know, this topic is almost 4 years old, but I am running in the same issue:
I like to give access to SMTP authentication with dovecot only for certain users in my OpenLDAP directory, which have a special attribute.
All my tests with user_filter and pass_filter are unsuccesful - dovecot ignores the additional attributes and simply passes all authentication requests.

```
user_filter = (&(userattribute=auth)(mail=%u))
```

The same ldap-query works fine with ldapsearch - but not with dovecot.
Any hints ?

EDIT: I found the solution:
Dovecot only uses the user_filter and pass_filter option when auth_bind is set to "no" and a user for authentication is configured (with option dn and dnpass). Otherwise those option would be ignored.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/573457)